# Regular expression to Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm having problems with a regular expression.

I want to get all `strings` containing "**start.aspx?page=start**" and "**start.aspx?page=start&F=yes**" and *not* any others like "**start.aspx?****page=startpage**"

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share, what you have tried yet, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as follows (note the optional part of `&F=yes`)

```
/start\.aspx\?page=start(\&F=yes)?/g
```

see it [running](https://regex101.com/r/eF2rH8/1)